# How can I teach tricks to my carey cat?

Tags: cats, training, leash-training, clicker-training, leashes

My cat is about 3 months old, she learned "sit" in 3 attempts and to stand on the back paws in just 2. She follows me without a leash, so I think she could learn more tricks, but I dont really know how.

Any advice?

Comment: to teach your cat tricks your cat needs to get something back from the training,cats do not work for free they know how capitalism work :)

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help], especially the topic [How to ask good questions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Can you please elaborate what exactly your problem is? You already managed to teach her 2 different tricks, why can't you teach her more? Please [edit] your question and describe your problem so we know how to help you better.